# Catch-all route in Symfony 3

Tags: php, routes, yaml, symfony

I have a catch-all fallback route in Symfony2 that I couldn't get to work in Symfony3.  I tried this exact syntax (a verbatim copy of my Symfony2 route) and that didn't work.

```
fallback:
    path:     /{req}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:catchAll }
    requirements:
        req: ".+"
```

How can I get this working in Symfony3?  (It's literally the only thing holding me back from using Symfony3 and keeping me at v2.8)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should help you:

```
route1:
  path: /{req}
  defaults: { _controller: 'AppBundle:Default:index' }
  requirements:
      req: ".+"
```

Where, my controller is called "DefaultController", and I have a function called "indexAction()".

Here is my code for the DefaultController:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
...
```

I actually did try what you said in my environment, and it didn't work until I had the right controller settings specified.

---

EDIT:

For this to work, it was necessary to add the parameter `Request $request` (*with* the type hint) to the action's method signature.

Comment: @TylerSebastian, I updated my post to show my DefaultController code. By the way I did test out the ops code to verify it did not work like he said, and then made the changes shown about and it does provide a catch all route. I simply verified by adding "/home" in my URL.

Comment: @AlvinBunk interesting, why do you suppose the `Request $request` parameter was needed?  There's little to no documentation on this, hence my question in the first place. Thanks, this seemed to work!

Comment: Hi there @bought777 . You don't need that. I just cut and paste a lot of code. You can use this: `public function indexAction()`

Comment: I tried it without $request as a param though and it didn't work. :O

Comment: I'd have to see the rest of the controller code that you have in order to duplicate what's happening. Regardless, I think you are set to go. Enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

I found the current accepted answer *almost* useful for **Symfony 4**, so I'm going to add my solution:

---

This is what I did to get it working in **Symfony 4**:

- Open  `/src/Controller/DefaultController.php`, make sure there is a function called `index(){}`

  - It's *not* required to add the `Request $request` as first param as some comment suggest.
  - This is the method that will handle *all* urls caught by the `routes.yaml`
- Open `/config/routes.yaml`, add this:

  ```
    yourRouteNameHere:
      path: /{req}
      defaults: { _controller: 'App\Controller\DefaultController::index' }
      requirements: #            the controller --^     the method --^
        req: ".*"`  # not ".+"
  ```

Comment: Why do you need index at all? Just make your controller invokable.

Comment: Because this way it's easier for beginners and easier to expand if you need e.g. an /admin as well.

Comment: @emix Magic methods? No thanks.  I use them quite sparingly and that's the advice I give most beginners: use them sparingly.

Comment: I'm not talking about `__set` or `__get`. The `__invoke` method is very handy, especially for controllers and CQ handlers. Such object can albo be type hinted with `callable` type.

Answer (score 0):

You can also [override Exception controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-exceptioncontroller).

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    exception_controller:  app.exception_controller:showAction

# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.exception_controller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\ExceptionController
        arguments: ['@twig', '%kernel.debug%']
```

```php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ExceptionController
{
    protected $twig;

    protected $debug;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, $debug)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->debug = $debug;
    }

    public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        // some action

        return new Response($this->twig->render('error/template.html.twig', [
                'status_code' => $exception->getStatusCode()
            ]
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a nice help but this isn't for exception handling.